# whats wrong in this code? why is it showing java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range?

Tags: java, string

```
  public static void main(String[] args)  {
           // TODO code application logic here
           Scanner in =new Scanner(System.in);
           long n=in.nextLong();
           int i,j,k;
           //byte k;
           int count=0;
           String str[];
           str= new String[100000];
           for(i=0;i<n;i++)
               str[i]=in.nextLine();
           for(i=0;i<n;i++) 
               for(j=0;j!=i&j<n;j++)
                   for(k=0;str[i].charAt(k)!=-1||str[j].charAt(k)!=-1;k++)
                   {
                       if(str[i].charAt(k)!=str[j].charAt(k))
                           break;
                       else
                           count++;
                   }




           System.out.print(count);   
}
```

Comment: You're never checking the length of your strings. Why *wouldn't* it throw an exception?

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Even printf debugging would show the  problem. Print the values of n and i as you loop. Points for using `length` property to confirm your guesses. See: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @Marvin `n` affects the array index, which isn't the immediate problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Did you come from a C background? This isn't how you check if you are at the end of a string in Java (even in C you'd want `&&` not `||` anyway):

```
str[i].charAt(k)!=-1||str[j].charAt(k)!=-1
```

What you want is something like:

```
k < str[i].length() && k < str[j].length()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to access a char in the string with invalid index.

```
for(i=0;i<n && i < str.length;i++) 
               for(j=0;j!=i&j<n;j++)
                   for(k=0;(str[i].length() > k && str[j].length() > k) ;k++)
                   {
                       if(str[i].charAt(k)!=str[j].charAt(k))
                           break;
                       else
                           count++;
                   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
for (i = 0; i <n; i++) {
        str[i] = br.readLine();
    }
```

instead of

```
 for (i = 0; i <n; i++) {
        str[i] = in.nextLine();
    }
```

Your all problem will be solved.

Or you can fired a blank

```
in.nextLine();
```

to skip the new line which is produced by pressing the enter key like this

```
 in.nextLine();
 for (i = 0; i <n; i++) {
        str[i] = in.nextLine();
    }
```

Comment: why would this solved the problem? He was getting ArrayOutOfBound not NullPointerException!

Comment: Thats because the in.nextInt() method does not consume the last newline character of the input (which was produced after pressing enter key), and in "for loop"  that newline is consumed in the next call to in.nextLine(). so in the loop when i =0 value was str[i=0]="\n" and when he tries to access the str[j=0].charAt(k=0)  he gets this error "java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException" because that string (str[j=0]) length is -1.